# If a graph with minimal degree greater than 1 has two components then performing a 2-switch with one pair in each component yields a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

If a graph $G$ has two components, and if $\delta (G) > 1$, then performing a 2-switch on one pair of vertices in one component and another pair in the other component gives a connected graph. Is this claim true? Thanks.

Comment: If we add an edge that connects some vertex of one component with some vertex of another component, our graph becomes connected. Is this your question?

Comment: @kabenyuk no, because a 2-switch also removes two edges. Also, I meant a 2-switch between 2 pairs, not 2 vertices. I'll edit that.